# did some pointer math and doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to learn pointers in c and with that purpose I redesigned a for loop to start at the end and loop to the beginning.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
    char* names[] = {"Alan", "Frank", "Mary", "John", "Lisa"};

    // safely get the size of ages
    int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;

    int* cur_age = ages;
    char** cur_name = names;

    // This is the original for loop:
    for (cur_name = names, cur_age = ages; (cur_age - ages) < count;
         cur_name++, cur_age++) {
        printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n", *cur_name, *cur_age);
    }

    // This is my version:
    for (cur_name = names + (count - 1), cur_age = ages + (count - 1);
         cur_age == ages; cur_name--, cur_age--) {
        printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n", *cur_name, *cur_age);
    }

    // I added this line and observed that cur_name is always equal to names +
    // 32
    // for example names: 0x7fff55268250, cur_name: 0x7fff55268270
    printf(" names: %p, cur_name: %p\n", names, cur_name);
}
```

The problem is that my version of the for loop prints nothing, although I've observed that the initialization of the pointers is in fact changing their value. I've checked the math and still can't figure out why this isn't working. Any enlightenment shall be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is wrong, it should be `cur_age >= ages`, not `cur_age == ages`.

The way you have it written, the loop condition is false on the first iteration, so the loop terminates immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The condition part of the loop

```
for (cur_name = names + (count - 1), cur_age = ages + (count - 1);
     cur_age == ages; cur_name--, cur_age--) {
    printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n", *cur_name, *cur_age);
}
```

looks like

```
cur_age == ages;
```

However initially `cur_age` was set to `cur_age = ages + (count - 1)`
So the loop iterate never or only one time when count is equal to 1.

Usually such loops are written the following way

```
for (cur_name = names + count, cur_age = ages + count;
     cur_age != ages; ) {
    printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n", *--cur_name, *--cur_age);
}
```